# How to print out the whole symbolic expression in Z3?

Tags: z3, z3py

I am using `Z3Py` for some analysis task, and for many times, I would like to print out the symbolic expression. For example,

```
a = BitVecVal("test", 32) + 13
print a
```

However, I find that once the `Z3` expression becomes quite large, it just cannot be print out fully. Instead, the "**ellipsis**" will be used quite often to simplify the expression...

So here is my question, how can I fully print out a `Z3` expression? Is there any specific API I could leverage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most scalable way is to use the SMT-LIB printer.
For example:

```
 x = Int('x')
 for i in range(12):
    x = x + x

 print x.sexpr()
```

will print:

```
(let ((a!1 (+ (+ (+ x x) (+ x x)) (+ (+ x x) (+ x x)))))
(let ((a!2 (+ (+ (+ a!1 a!1) (+ a!1 a!1)) (+ (+ a!1 a!1) (+ a!1 a!1)))))
(let ((a!3 (+ (+ (+ a!2 a!2) (+ a!2 a!2)) (+ (+ a!2 a!2) (+ a!2 a!2)))))
  (+ (+ (+ a!3 a!3) (+ a!3 a!3)) (+ (+ a!3 a!3) (+ a!3 a!3))))))
```

You can control parameters on the formatter used by the pretty printer using the function 'set_pp_option'. You would have to look in the source code of z3printer.py to determine which options would do the trick.